# What happens in parameterized virtuality?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

Chapter 16.4 *Parameterized Virtuality* in the *C++ Templates - The Complete Guide*, by David Vandevoorde and Nicolai M. Josuttis, says:

> C++ allows us to parameterize directly three kinds of entities through
>   templates: types, constants ("nontypes"), and templates. However,
>   indirectly, it also allows us to parameterize other attributes such as
>   the virtuality of a member function.

The following code was illustrated in that chapter:

```
#include <iostream>

struct NotVirtual
{};

struct IsVirtual
{
    virtual void func() {;}
};

//---------------------//

template<typename T>
struct Base : T
{
    void func()
    { std::cout<< "Base::func()" <<std::endl; }
};

template<typename T>
struct Derived : Base<T>
{
    void func()
    { std::cout<< "Derived::func()" <<std::endl; }
};

//---------------------//

int main()
{
    Base<NotVirtual> *p1 = new Derived<NotVirtual>();
    p1->func();
    delete p1;

    Base<IsVirtual> *p2 = new Derived<IsVirtual>();
    p2->func();
    delete p2;
}
```

Example online: https://rextester.com/OAGC66937

I understand the usage of such a technique, but unfortunately the book does not provide any further details as to how this thing happens. I can see that `Base` is actually a derived class inheriting from the template parameter `T`.

**Questions:**

1. What happens in the background during parameterized virtuality?
2. Does something happen in the resulting v_table?
3. How does the `virtual` from the template parameter get transferred over?

Comment: Once the `Base` template is specialized for a specific `T`, everything proceeds as usual through inheritance and virtual overriding. There's no special-casing for virtual functions or anything. Where exactly are you lost?

Comment: @Quentin: Shouldn't `Base::func` be virtual if it is a base class of the `Derived`?

Comment: No, you can very well inherit and hide functions from a parent class without them being `virtual`, only they won't be dynamically dispatched of course. Do note that `Base` and `Derived` are templates, not classes, which is crucial to understanding how they generate two completely separate class chains upon instantiation. The trick demonstrated here is injecting `IsVirtual` at the top of the inheritance chain, so that it actually declares a `virtual` `func` that then remains `virtual` throughout the derived classes. This makes it look like `Base`'s `func` has "become" `virtual`.

Comment: Not per sé. Depends on implementation and goal of the programmer. Not declaring a function virtual and redclaring it in a derived class is perfectly valid.

Comment: @Quentin: This part is what I wasn't clear on: "... remains virtual throughout the derived classes". I thought that by having the `Base::func()` as `non-virtual`, the `Derived` would be `non-virtual` too. I didn't know that by declaring the function `virtual` two levels up in the inheritance chain, that it would still remain `virtual`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand upon @Quentin's comment

> Once the Base template is specialized for a specific T, everything proceeds as usual through inheritance and virtual overriding.

Let's write out an equivalent non-template set of classes

```
struct BaseNV : NotVirtual
{
    void func() // first definition of func
    { std::cout<< "Base::func()" <<std::endl; }
};

struct DerivedNV : BaseNV 
{
    void func() // hides BaseNV::func
    { std::cout<< "Derived::func()" <<std::endl; }
};

struct BaseIV : IsVirtual
{
    void func() // implicitly virtual, overrides IsVirtual::func
    { std::cout<< "Base::func()" <<std::endl; }
};

struct DerivedIV : BaseIV
{
    void func() // implicitly virtual, overrides BaseIV::func (and IsVirtual::func)
    { std::cout<< "Derived::func()" <<std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    BaseNV *p1 = new DerivedNV();
    p1->func();
    delete p1;

    BaseIV *p2 = new DerivedIV();
    p2->func();
    delete p2;
}
```

[See it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7ea8fa74bc165d05)

> What happens in the background during parameterized virtuality?

`Base<T>` inherits from `T`, and follows the rules of inheritance

> Does something happen in the resulting v_table?

Only the ordinary `virtual` mechanisms. Specifically, in the `NotVirtual` case there *aren't* any virtual functions, so there probably won't be any vtables.

> How does the virtual from the template parameter get transferred over?

By the normal rules of inheritance

Comment: @Quentin oops, indeed

Comment: Thanks. This comment here was very usefull: `// implicitly virtual, overrides IsVirtual::func`. I didn't know that declaring the function `virtual` two levels up in the inheritance chain, would still remain `virtual`.