# Can I force a subclass to override both functions or neither?

Tags: c++, inheritance

Suppose I have class that provides some virtual methods. Some function are not mandatory to be overriden, but I need to make sure that if a class overrides a specific method, then the second method related to the first one must also be overriden.

Here's some code to explain this:

```
struct Base {
  virtual void f();
  virtual void g();
};

struct Good1 : Base {
  void f() override;
  void g() override;
};

struct Good2 : Base {
};

struct Bad1 : Base {
  void f() override;
};

struct Bad2 : Base {
  void g() override;
};
```

I want the `Good` classes to compile, but not the `Bad` ones. Is this possible?

Comment: How about creating new abstract class with those 2 functions. Then your subclass can exclude or include to inherit that

Comment: You could make both functions pure virtual with a default implementation. Then, if the implementer wants, they can call the base class implementations.

Comment: I edited the question, and added a code sample. Please edit/rollback if I misunderstood the question.

Comment: What do these functions do? What would happen if a user of your code implemented only one of them?

Answer (score 2):

You could use static_assert to produce compile time errors and CRTP + typeinfo to detect if all or none methods were overriden.

```
#include <typeinfo>

template <typename B, typename T> constexpr bool are_both_overriden(){
    return ((std::is_same<decltype(&B::f),decltype(&T::f)>::value && std::is_same<decltype(&B::g),decltype(&T::g)>::value)
    || (!std::is_same<decltype(&B::f),decltype(&T::f)>::value && !std::is_same<decltype(&B::g),decltype(&T::g)>::value));
}

template <typename D>
struct Base
{
  virtual void f() {}
  virtual void g() {}
  Base(){
      static_assert (are_both_overriden<Base, D>(), "Base requires all or none methods overriden");
  }
};

struct Good1 : Base<Good1> {
  void f() override{
  }
  void g() override{
  }
};

struct Good1 : Base<Good1> {
};

struct Bad1 : Base<Bad1> {
  void f() override{
  }
};//WILL PRODUCE COMPILER ERROR

struct Bad1 : Base<Bad1> {
  void g() override{
  }
};//WILL PRODUCE COMPILER ERROR
```

Comment: The function can be simplified to `return std::is_same_v<decltype(&B::f), decltype(&T::f)> == std::is_same_v<decltype(&B::g), decltype(&T::g)>;`.

Comment: For anyone wondering how it works: If a class inherits a method without overriding it, then `&Derived::method` will have `Base::*` in its type, instead of `Derived::*`.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s something you could try using an inheritance technique called Mixins. Essentially you parameterize the virtuality through template parameters. These template parameters correspond to classes that either do nothing, or make the two functions pure virtual meaning you must override them in your derived class. If you choose to do nothing, no worries, the default function definitions are called. To run the code, see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/vhd5fz).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class NotVirtual 
{
public:
    void f1() { std::cout << "Do nothing" << std::endl; }
    void f2() { std::cout << "Do nothing" << std::endl; }
};

class Virtual 
{
public:
    virtual ~Virtual() = default;

    virtual void f1() = 0;
    virtual void f2() = 0;
};

template<typename Virtuality>
class Base : public Virtuality {};

template<typename Virtuality>
class Derived : public Base<Virtuality>
{
public:
    void f1() { std::cout << "Do something in f1()" << std::endl; }
    void f2() { std::cout << "Do something in f2()" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Base<NotVirtual>> pNotVirtual = std::make_unique<Derived<NotVirtual>>();
    pNotVirtual->f1();    // Prints: Do nothing
    pNotVirtual->f2();    // Prints: Do nothing

    std::unique_ptr<Base<Virtual>> pVirtual = std::make_unique<Derived<Virtual>>();
    pVirtual->f1();    // Prints: Do something in f1()
    pVirtual->f2();    // Prints: Do something in f2()
}
```

Now, if you uncomment one of the derived f1() or f2() definitions, you get an error message, with a note along the lines of `unimplemented pure virtual method 'f2' in 'Derived'`

Note: this technique was adapted from some sample code in the book C++ Templates by David Vandevoorde, Nicolai M. Josuttis, and Douglas Gregor. You can read more about it there or on this stack overflow question asking about this same example: [What happens in parameterized virtuality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55472947/what-happens-in-parameterized-virtuality).

Comment: isn't this just a C++ re-imagination of an Interface?

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie yes effectively, as I was trying to get the desired behavior, the implementation of the two functions had to be moved out of the base class completely. Now you just inherit the interface you need, either both or neither

Comment: This is an interesting idea, but I'm not sure if it's useful in OP's case. With this you no longer have a common base class, and the functions are no longer virtual in one of the cases. Also I don't get why you'd make `Base` and `Derived` templates (or why have `Base` at all, instead of directly inheriting from `Virtuality`).